# Dropbox Sync api using multiple Activities

Tags: android, dropbox-api

### I want to use an Activity to verificate the current used dropbox Account:

Therefor the first Activity initializes the dbxAccount Object.
This instance is than passed on to the second Activity which "should" use this to upload data.

Every time the dbxFileSystem is used, the Application crashed down showing a: **disk I/O error**

```
        public class Upload extends Activity {
    private static final String appKey = "xxx";
    private static final String appSecret = "yyy";

    private static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;
    DbxFileSystem dbxFs;
    DbxFile imageLocationDbxF;
    DbxPath protocollFile;
    private DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr;
    String dataPath;
    Button retry;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(),
                appKey, appSecret);
        onClickLinkToDropbox();

        Button getBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backId);
        retry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retry);
        retry.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        getBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DbxAccount chosenAccount=mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount();

//-----> here the dbxAccount Object is delivered <------

                MovementDetection.mAccount=chosenAccount;
                Intent sendAccount = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManueActivity.class);
                startActivity(sendAccount);
            }
        });
        retry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClickLinkToDropbox();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mDbxAcctMgr.hasLinkedAccount()) {
            // showLinkedView();
            try {
                dbxFs = DbxFileSystem
                        .forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());
                Log.i(TAG, "Account linked!!!");

                // -> check if the folder exists!
            } catch (Unauthorized e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            retry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void onClickLinkToDropbox() {
        mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity) this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i("", "Linked---!!");

            } else {
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Calling methods to upload or create images/files/folder... works inside this Activity. But this Activity is used for verification of the currently used dropbox account only.

The second Activity now has an inizialized **dbxAccount** Object. It is described as a **static variable**. *( ---> see in this comment <--- )*
The second Activity is than called via the Intent

```
public class MovementDetection extends Activity implements
    CvCameraViewListener2 {


private CameraView mOpenCvCameraView;
public static DbxAccount mAccount;
public DbxFileSystem dbxFs;
DbxFile imageLocationDbxF;
private DbxPath DestinationFolder;
private static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // do some stuff here
    Log.i(TAG, "the linked account is: "+mAccount.getAccountInfo());
    // Log cat shows normal contents of this Object as it should

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAccount.isLinked()) {
        // showLinkedView();
        try {
            dbxFs = DbxFileSystem
                    .forAccount(mAccount);
            Log.i(TAG, "Account linked!!!");    

        } catch (Unauthorized e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "no linkedAccount found");
    }
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this,
            mLoaderCallback);
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // does some stuff here....

    DbxFile testFile= dbxFs.create(new DbxPath("hello.txt"));
    //here the program stops!

    return inputFrame.rgba();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i("", "Linked---!!");

        } else {
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

here is my manifest.xml

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.opencv.Pulsdetection"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
android:versionCode="21"
android:versionName="2.1" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="org.opencv.MotionControl.Main"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.opencv.MotionControl.ManueActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.opencv.MotionControl.CameraChose"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_camera_chose" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.opencv.Camera.CameraChose"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_camera_chose" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.opencv.Camera.ShowAndUpload"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_and_upload" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="xxxx" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="Dropbox Sync"/>
    <activity
        android:name="org.dropbox.connect.ConnectToDropbox"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_connect_to_dropbox" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.FileSystems.LookUpPath"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_look_up_path" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.dropbox.connect.ShowAndUploadImages"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_and_upload_images" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.dropbox.connect.Upload"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_upload" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.dropbox.connect.AccountManager"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_account_manager" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.opencv.MotionControl.MovementDetection"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_open_viedo"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>


</application>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Since this is my first question here, i am sorry for the format and i don't know how to post the error Code either..

I looking forward for an anwser
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not set a static variable on an Activity

```
// do not do this!
MovementDetection.mAccount=chosenAccount;
```

When the user has linked to an account, it will stay linked in the lifetime of the app (until uninstalled or explicitly unlinked).

When you wish to access Dropbox in other activities (after linking - could be part of a one-time setup or similar)

```
    DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(
            getApplicationContext(), DROPBOX_APPKEY,
            DROPBOX_SECRETKEY);
    try {
        if (mDbxAcctMgr.hasLinkedAccount()
                && mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount().isLinked()) {
            dbxFs = DbxFileSystem
                    .forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());
        } else {
            /* Might want to navigate to Dropbox signup Activity here */
        }
    } catch (Unauthorized e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e); 
    } catch (InvalidPathException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (DbxException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

After this step `dbxFs` is initialized and ready for usage, otherwise it is null due to an exception.

Comment: I thought as long as the variable is public static only, the variable can be re-initialized by calling the first activity (upload), since the current linkedAccount from the startLink(); method delivered depends on the data the user is giving the Activity called in this method, why isn't this so?

Comment: Actually creating a new Instace of DbxAccountManager and initzialising it throug getInstance(); works (problem basicly solved)! why doesn't setting DbxAccount as a static variable works then (just curious)?

Comment: I cannot say exactly what went wrong in your situation. But is very unreliable to store static variables on Activities - You never know if the OS kills your app when in background for instance, then you are left with a null pointer. What I think happened in your case is that you initially set the static variable, then you start the Activity (which creates a new Activity by default in Android). The new instance has never gotten the static variable set. In short it is very difficult to manage. If you want to do something like that, then you should do it in an extension of Application.

Comment: Well it works pretty fine now,thanks again. I found out, that the DbxAccount Object get useless when it is passed to antoher activity or Class as an object and used inside an instance.